# Ошибка в отправке сообщения ботом telegram

Tags: python, telegram, telebot

Я пытаюсь написать бота обратной поддержки. Администратор отвечает на написанное пользователем сообщение после чего бот его отправляет пользователю. Вот функция, которая должна была это исполнить:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def text(message):
    if int(message.chat.id) == int("admin-chat-id"):
        bot.send_message(message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id, message.text)
    else:
        bot.forward_message("admin-chat-id", message.chat.id, message.message_id)
        bot.send_message("admin-chat-id", message.from_user.id)
```

Однако я получаю такую ошибку:

```
bot.send_message(message.reply_to_message.forward_from.id, message.text)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Честно, не понимаю в чём здесь может быть ошибка. Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

Comment: А откуда взялось forward_from? Откуда боту знать кому отправлять ответ администратора? Каким образом это у тебя реализовано?

Comment: Когда пользователь пишет своё сообщение, бот пересылает его в чат с администратором. Когда администратор отвечает на сообщение, бот должен его отправить обратно пользователю.
Я пытался убрать forward_from, однако появлялась ошибка "Threaded polling exception: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. Error code: 400. Description: Bad Request: chat not found".
Главная проблема и заключается в том, как реализовать пересылку сообщений от чата администратора к пользователю